# In Java, is writing a single function or class to handle arbitrary multidimensional ArrayList possible?

Tags: java, c++, templates, multidimensional-array, generic-programming

In C++, I can write 2 template classes, like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
template <typename T>
class Printer{
public:
    static void print(T& v){
        printf("%d ",v.getValue());
    }
};

template <typename T,typename Alloc>
class Printer<std::vector<T,Alloc> >{
public:
    static void print(std::vector<T,Alloc>& v){
        for(T& e : v){
            Printer<T>::print(e);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
};
```

so that it can accept arbitrary custom object type and `vector` in `vector` in `vector`... (infinity nested `vector`):

```
class Student{
public:
    int value;
    Student(int value){ this->value=value; }
    int getValue() const { return this->value; }
};

class Teacher{
public:
    int value;
    Teacher(int value){ this->value=value; }
    int getValue() const { return this->value*10; }
};

int main(){
    std::vector<Student> v2 = {Student(10),Student(20)};
    Printer<std::vector<Student> >::print(v2);

    std::vector<std::vector<Teacher> > v3 = {{Teacher(30),Teacher(40)},{Teacher(50),Teacher(60),Teacher(70)}};
    Printer<std::vector<std::vector<Teacher> > >::print(v3);
    return 0;
}
```

provided the custom object `Student` and `Teacher` has `getValue()` function.

But in Java, how can I write something like above that accepts both

```
ArrayList<Student > v2;
```

and

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Teacher> > v3;
```

(and also `ArrayList` in `ArrayList` in `ArrayList` in...) in generic way?

Few problems occurs when I tried to convert the code, first, the generic object method cannot compile:

```
public static void <T> print(T t){
    System.out.print(t.getValue());
}
```

and I don't know how to convert `std::vector< T , Alloc >` in to Java because `ArrayList` only accepts 1 template parameter.

Note: I want vector to be the specialized template because when I want to add support of `int`:

```
std::vector<int> v1={1,2};
Printer<std::vector<int> >::print(v1);
```

I can just add

```
template <>
class Printer<int>{
public:
    static void print(int& v){
        printf("%d ",v);
    }
};
```

to the code.

Comment: I don't see why you need two `Printer` classes instead of two overloaded functions? Or better yet, overload the `operator<<` function to handle the actual classes?

Comment: Sure it's possible. It may be ugly and it may be less generic than you think, but it's definitely possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `instanceof` checks:

```
public static <T> void print(List<? extends T> list) {
    for (final T t : list) {
        if (t instanceof List) print((List) t);
        else System.out.println(t);
    }
}
```

But of course you can not use a method `T.getValue()` if it is not defined anywhere in an interface or somewhere. If `T` is an interface

```
public interface T {
    String getValue();
}
```

then you have something like this

```
public static void print(List<? extends Object> list) {
    for (Object t : list) {
        if(t instanceof T) System.out.println(((T)t).getValue());
        else if (t instanceof List) print((List) t);
        else continue; // I don't know this type.
    }
}
```

But it is then attached to your Interface `T`. The Problem is really that you can't access methods, which are not defined, at least not without Reflections. How does C++ do this anyway?

**EDIT:** This will of course not work, if you have an implementation of `T` which also implements the `List` interface.

Comment: The big difference to C++ is that in C++, the **compiler** creates **specific** code for template usages. Thats the thing: in java, there is only ONE list class - dealing with objects. In C++, each template usage leads to **another** binary output - built exactly for *that* use case. But I like your answer - it gives some specific advise that I left out in my answer. My vote for that!

Answer (score 2):

There is one simple, but very ugly solution: turn to [raw types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html), or as that is super bad practice, go for `? extends Object`.

You see, in the end, Java generics are simply not a match to modern day C++ templates. Generics are not templates - example: you can't use them for primitive types, such as `int`. You can only work with `List<Integer>` instead. Or some `T extends Number` when you need a list that takes Double, Float, ... objects as well.

The point is: in the end, at runtime, all of those "generics" are gone. All such lists simply contain **Object**s.

So, theoretically, if you really want a "solution", then you could go for

```
void foo(List<? extends Object> thingies)
```

avoiding all type information ... and doing reflection magic at runtime to determine how to deal with the exact contents of that list.

A "more Java" solution requires you to **step back**. As said, Java isn't C++, so you simply should not expect the same level of "expressiveness" from Java.

Instead: learn how to *properly* make use of Java generics and the Java type system; and build a solution based on *that* knowledge*.

Or in other words: if you need a C++ solution, use C++. Java will never meet that requirement (at least not to 100%).